# Cross compile Kernel drivers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I am new at Linux kernel and I try to make a cross compile to build a driver for imx6, previusly I created the kernel using Yocto1.8 (this works ok). I have a linux distribution of 64 bits, and the arm inside imx6 is based in 32 bits

I have this configuration in my makefile:

```
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
export PRODUCT_NAME PRODUCT_VERSION
export ROOTDIR
export PCIE X86 PL330 
export KDIR=~/src/imx6/yocto/build/tmp/work-shared/cgtqmx6/kernel-source/
```

but doing "make" the compilation generates these errors:

[image: screenshot]

I think the problem is due to the differents distribution (64 and 32bits) but I don´t know sure.

If anybody can help me ... thanks!!!

Comment: You perhaps have to understand how to build in-tree modules separately from the rest. You also need to have proper `.config` file applied and like someone said below `ARCH` environment set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are x86 compiler options.

You probably need to add `ARCH=arm`.